# HLS stream from multiple FFMPEG to RTMP command at VideoJS keep repeating for segments

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, video.js, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I am building on demand video streaming application based on user interaction at frontend  using FFMPEG and RTMP, which eventually converted to HLS using nginx-rtmp-module, with hls_continuous flag set to true.

While running back to back FFMPEG command to RTMP(i.e. once one FFMPEG command done with execution at RTMP stream, another FFMPEG command is executed at same stream), observation at VideoJs player that some of the HLS segment keeps repeating.

Would be great help if someone could help me to figure out what could be possible reason, and how to fix the same?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code to this example
https://videojs.github.io/videojs-contrib-hls/

Comment: This is the exact source I have refered for development, but unfortunately this one is not working  as expected.